# Как по-русски назвать — «versi incatenati»?

Tags: перевод, терминология

Есть такая вещь, для которой итальянское название — «versi incatenati». Так называются стихи, из которых каждый следующий начинается с того же слова, которым завершается предыдущий. Как такая вещь называется по-русски? Пример (прошу прощения за глупость — просто чтобы показать, как это по-русски может выглядеть):

```
Собака попала в подвал,
Подвал был сырой и холодный.
Холодный сбирается вал;
Вал — душегубец не модный…
```

И так далее по цепочке…

Есть схожее явление — «catena di sonetti», венок сонетов. Это сонеты, из которых каждый следующий начинается с того же стиха, которым завершается предыдущий. Но меня интересует русское название для другой вещи…

**Добавление**: слово должно явственно указывать, что речь идёт о шуточной поэзии. То есть такой, цель которой — в первую очередь, соответствие текста форме. В интернете можно найти довольно много примеров «палиндромических» стихов разного рода. В таких стихах смысл если и есть (как бывает в пословных или построчных ракоходах), то всё же очевидно, что он — совсем не главное или не совсем главное. Вот о чём-то таком я и говорю.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This one I know) Actually it is called `aнадиплосис`. Here's a quote from dictionary:

Анадиплосис - стилистическая фигура, состоящая в том, что отрезок речи (стих, фраза) начинается словами, которыми заканчивается предыдущий, например "Голова болит, мало можется. Мало можется, нездоровится".

This was quite widely used in Old Russian poetry as well, here's an example from relevant [wiki article](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81):

> Станем-ка, ребята челобитную писать,
>
> Челобитную писать, во Москву посылать.
>
> Во Москву посылать, царю в руки подавать.

Strictly speaking it is not the name of a poetry of such kind but rather of the act of repetition itself but in Russian one would say "стихи с использованием анадиплосиса" - this is the closest you can get if not to dive in "I-am-too-smart-kind" self-induced neologisms, something like "анадиплосисческие стихи" ;)

Comment: Спасибо большое, очень полезный ответ! Есть дополнительная трудность: ваше слово — это название стилистической _фигуры_; а я на самом деле ищу слово для обозначения таких _стихов_, для которых применение этой стилистической фигуры — самая главная характеристика, даже единственная определяющая. Шуточная поэзия особого рода (примерно того же назначения, что палиндромы/анациклы)…

Comment: @Evgeniy добавил комментарий )

Comment: Прочитал комментарий. Честно скажу, «лишние» (несущие мало самостоятельного смысла) слова вроде «использования» — это для моих целей самые настоящие «душегубцы». :) Но за явным отсутствием лучшего ответа — принимаю этот…

Comment: @V.V. триолет - это повторение определённой строки в определённых местах, вилланелла не знаю что такое, но триолет - не совсем то.

Comment: @V.V. Судя по примеру в английской Википедии, вилланелла — это тоже совсем не то (даже по характеру стихосложения). Вообще-то здесь, кроме характера стихосложения, важна ещё цель. Это такая вещь, которую интеллектуалы/поэты создают, когда им нечего делать или когда они хотят отработать поэтическую технику (подбор слов, …) Потому никакого близкого к практической жизни смысла («из души выпелось», и так далее) в этих стихах и не должно быть. Для читателя или слушателя — это шутка, игра слов. Потому любая разновидность «народной» поэзии — это не то…